# How to pause an Azure Devops stage

Tags: azure-devops, octopus-deploy, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a multi-stage devops build. Towards the end will publish to octopus deploy and trigger a release. We are not using releases in Devops for this.

We want to not mark the devops build as complete until octopus has finished but also not hold up an agent polling octopus.

You can set a stage in devops to require manual intervention which has the desired effect with the exception it requires manual work. There does not seem to be an API for this.

Is there a way to do this without holding up many agents just polling octopus deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that what fits for you is the [`Approvals and Check`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#invoke-rest-api) feature from Azure Devops.

It can be set to invoke a Rest Api and evaluate the request results to proceed a deploy job.
[image]

Surely you must need do some changes in your pipeline, add a Environment to acts like a virtual gate of your pipeline's ending and this kind of things, but in my experience it worths.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You are looking for the [Manual Validation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

```
jobs:
  - job: waitForValidation
    displayName: Wait for external validation
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          test@test.com
          example@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'resume'
```

Comment: Can the intervention be done via an API though? Octopus should be the thing to intervene, not a human.